# Installing custom fonts for the xfce terminal

Tags: terminal, fonts, xfce

I would like to run an ASCII game in the terminal, but it requires the text to be perfectly square to look proper, how would I download and install a square font on the xfce terminal?

Comment: Please see if this helps you. ......   https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/jimkq1/can_you_install_and_use_fonts_on_xfce/